# is there any JOOMLA XML class?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

```
$hold=$this->load_component_objects();
```

$hold contain result of my query i made in my table during JOOMLA component development. Now is there any JOOMLA XML library or class that is capable of converting it to XML automatically.

Comment: or i have to write my own function!!!!

Comment: Why do you want it in XML?

Comment: to send it to client. i.e. to use in javascript at client side

Comment: Why not JSON encode it? That would be simpler than converting it to XML and trying to parse it back into objects in javascript.

Comment: yup you are right. but i realized it later. On remaining pages i have intentions to use JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is no.

The only XML handling is in `JFactory`, and it's mainly used by the installer when reading extension manifests.

Basically the installer gets the XML file path retrieves the XML in it's various `loadManifestFromXML($xmlfile)` methods. These in turn just call `JFactory::getXML($xmlfile)` which is really just a wrapper on [`simplexml` (PHP manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and return it as a `JXMLElement`.

```
class JXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    ... 
}
```

*N.B. you can pass a XML string to `getXML()` as well as a file path.*

More information on your objects structure, would help in determining the best way to get it into an XML format.

Comment: Are you thinking of in 2.5?

Comment: Yes - the OP question is tagged 2.5 :D

Comment: ha ok.  I mean obviously you can write xml in joomla, we produce feeds among other things. You do need a doc type.